# TextMate: Shortcut to go to the first non-whitespace character in the line

Tags: textmate

I really like TextMate. However, after using it for a long time and searching several times, I haven't been able to find a shortcut that takes me to the beginning of the line the way I want.  I commonly want the cursor at the beginning of the line, but after the whitespace.

For example, in the following code if the cursor is at the end of the line with `puts 'hi'`, and then I type `⌘ ←`, it will put the cursor at the very beginning of the line, and I would rather that it put the cursor next to the 'p' at the beginning of the line.  Is there such a shortcut?

```
class Test
  def greet
    puts 'hi'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not a one-keypress solution, when I want to do that I press...

1. CMD + ←
2. OPT + →

Comment: True.  That's what I do too.  I suppose that I could create a macro and override the ⌘ ← shortcut.

Comment: That's a good idea. Let me know if you make it. I wouldn't mind it myself :)

Comment: I made the macro and I had been trying it out for a little while when I found a fundamental problem with this.  If there is actually text at the beginning of the line, I don't want it to automatically do the `⌥→` afterwards.

Comment: -1 Not only doesn't work as @dontangg pointed out, but also skips some control chars and goes straight to the first letter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have textmate installed at the moment but I believe you can record a macro that jumps to the beginning of the line then searches forward for `(?<=\s*)(?=[^\s]+)`.

Answer (score 1):

It has been nicely explained [here](http://blog.peterhaza.no/textmate-tip-go-to-first-non-space-character-on-current-line/):

> - Press ⌥⌘M to start recording a macro
> - Press ⌘← to go to the beginning of the line
> - Press ⌘F and search for [^\s]|\n with regular expressions enabled (Thanks to Abhi Beckert)
> - Press ← to go to beginning of selection(unselecting)
> - Press ⌥⌘M to stop recording the macro.
> - Press ⌃⌘M to save your macro
> - Give the macro a name and a key equivalent (I used ⌘← to overwrite the normal go to beginning of line behaviour)

I bound `home` to this macro.